# Optimize Select query with mutiple JOINS, Sub queries and MIN MAX

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize the below query, it works well but very slowly. The sub queries are iterating through the entire tables multiple times

There challenge is, there are 3 situations where I need to get the lowest value from the JOINS where value is not blank and 1 situation where the JOIN is supposed to get the highest row value. I have used MIN and Max

Is there a better approach that i can use to create this query ?

The below are lowest value columns where value is not blank. I am using MIN() sub-query with a JOIN

```
j4.owner_perception, 
j6.tl_perception,
```

The below are highest value columns. I am using MAX() sub-query with a JOIN

```
j2.tl_perception, 
j2.owner_perception
```

The Query

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 
  s.ticket_number, 
  s.request_id,
  j4.owner_perception, 
  j6.tl_perception,
  j2.tl_perception, 
  j2.owner_perception 
FROM 
  survey 
  LEFT JOIN survey AS s ON survey.id = s.id 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      request_id, 
      MIN(id) AS minumumownerid 
    FROM 
      history_gt 
    WHERE 
      owner_perception != "" 
    GROUP BY 
      request_id
  ) AS j3 ON s.request_id = j3.request_id 
  LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j4 ON j4.id = j3.minumumownerid 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      request_id, 
      MIN(id) AS minumumtlid 
    FROM 
      history_gt 
    WHERE 
      tl_perception != "" 
    GROUP BY 
      request_id
  ) AS j5 ON s.request_id = j5.request_id 
  LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j6 ON j6.id = j5.minumumtlid 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      request_id, 
      MAX(id) AS maximumid 
    FROM 
      history_gt 
    GROUP BY 
      request_id
  ) AS j1 ON s.request_id = j1.request_id 
  LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j2 ON j2.id = j1.maximumid 
GROUP BY 
  s.request_id 
ORDER BY 
  s.id ASC 
LIMIT 
  50
```

This is the EXPLAIN Details (I do not understand EXPLAIN :)

```
+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|  id  | select_type  |   table     |  type   |  possible_keys    |    key      | key_len  |        ref         |  rows    |                    Extra                     |  |
+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|   1  | PRIMARY      | survey      | index   | NULL              | request_id  |     767  | NULL               |     476  | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | s           | eq_ref  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY     |       4  | qo.survey.id       |       1  |                                              |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | <derived2>  | ref     | key0              | key0        |     153  | qo.s.request_id    |    1060  | Using where                                  |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | j4          | eq_ref  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY     |       4  | j3.minumumownerid  |       1  | Using where                                  |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | <derived3>  | ref     | key0              | key0        |     153  | qo.s.request_id    |    2121  | Using where                                  |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | j6          | eq_ref  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY     |       4  | j5.minumumtlid     |       1  | Using where                                  |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | <derived4>  | ref     | key0              | key0        |     153  | qo.s.request_id    |     530  | Using where                                  |  |
|   1  | PRIMARY      | j2          | eq_ref  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY     |       4  | j1.maximumid       |       1  | Using where                                  |  |
|   4  | DERIVED      | history_gt  | range   | NULL              | request_id  |     152  | NULL               |  252406  | Using index for group-by                     |  |
|   3  | DERIVED      | history_gt  | index   | NULL              | request_id  |     152  | NULL               | 1009620  | Using where                                  |  |
|   2  | DERIVED      | history_gt  | index   | owner_perception  | request_id  |     152  | NULL               | 1009620  | Using where                                  |  |
+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: On the information provided, it's almost impossible to say. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) (Although i would observe that LIMIT without ORDER BY is almost meaningless)

Comment: Also, the first JOIN seems to be redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry have made the query smaller

Comment: @Sebastian pls fix formatting issues (especially remove all the leading spaces in the code block; so that more content gets visible without doing horizontal scrolling). Also, regarding your query: problem with your current approach is that in the Derived tables (subqueries in the From clause), complete tables are being scanned, and then only a small amount of that subquery result is used after JOIN condition filtering. *Generally*, in these scenarios, a correlated subquery in SELECT clause (with proper indexing) can be much more efficient. But pls fix formatting first..

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya i tried removing the spaces before the EXPLAIN table, but its then just coming as text

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your original is bulky and going through the history table 3 times.  My suggestion is to do conditional query against all records in history ONCE.  Notice my "PQ" (prequery) that groups by request id and does a respective min/max based on CASE WHEN of the != "" qualification.  If it does not apply, return null which is ignored as a result.  I then apply coalesce() to prevent nulls from coming back from that result set.  Now I have all your aggregates in 1 result set.

Now that is available, I removed your redundant Survey to Survey S join and went directly from the survey to the prequery result.  Now I can left join from the prequery back to history on each of their respective min/max IDs.

```
SELECT 
      s.ticket_number, 
      s.request_id,
      j4.owner_perception, 
      j6.tl_perception,
      j2.tl_perception, 
      j2.owner_perception 
    FROM 
      survey s
         left join
         (SELECT 
                request_id, 
                coalesce( min( case when owner_perception != ""
                   then id else null end ), 0 ) minOwnerID,
                coalesce( min( case when tl_perception != ""
                   then id else null end ), 0 ) minTLID,
                MAX(id) AS maxID
             FROM 
                history_gt 
             GROUP BY 
                request_id ) PQ
            on s.request_id = PQ.request_id
             LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j4 
                ON PQ.minOwnerID = j4.id
             LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j6 
                ON PQ.minTLID = j6.id
             LEFT JOIN history_gt AS j2 
                ON PQ.maxID = j2.id
   GROUP BY 
      s.request_id 
   ORDER BY 
      s.id ASC 
   LIMIT 
      50
```